# invalid keystore format while generating signed app

Tags: android

I have few applications up and running in google play store, in earlier version of android studio what was installed on **Laptop Machine-1** I used to update my application (myTaskApp.app) in play store successfully with following example of `key store` file.

Example:

> Key Store Password: test123
>
> Key alias: test_key
>
> Key Password: test123

After shift to new **Laptop Machine-2** with new android studio version I am not able to generating signed app with `same key store` file to update the application.

I am getting following error. Screen shot is attached:

Invalid keystore format
[image]